# Checking if something exists and adding or getting an object from django

Tags: python, django, web-scraping

I'm scrapping a shop from Woocommerce, and i'd like to take the products brand name, and compare if there's already name like this in the database and if so put the id of it in our base and if not, create an instance of a productProducer

```
        for page in range (99, 100):
            parameters = {'per_page': 1, 'page': f'{page}', 'stock_status': 'instock', 'status': 'publish'}
            products = wcapi.get("products", params=parameters).json()

            for product in products:
                print(product)
                name = product['name']
                slug = product['slug']
                description = product['description']
                id = product['id']
                price = product['price']
                link = product['permalink']

                for brands in product['images']:
                    brands_name = brands['name']

                for image in product['images']:
                    src = image['src']

                print(product['categories'])
                parsed_categories = []
                for category in product['categories']:
                    parsed_categories.append(dir[str(category['id'])])
                print(parsed_categories)
                
                db_product = Product.objects.create(name=name, slug=slug, product_producer_id=1, unique_id=int(id),
                                            description=description)
                db_product.product_category.set(parsed_categories)
                ProductInStore.objects.create(product=db_product, store_id=1, price=price, currency='PLN', url=link)
                ProductImage.objects.create(product=db_product, url=src)
```

I have a dir with mapping keys and values for parsing categories outside.

Models look like this:

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    filename = models.FileField(upload_to='ecommerce_product_img/', null=True, blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True,blank=True)

class ProductProducer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=False, editable=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Id like to check if brands_name already exists in productProducer_name and if not, create a new instance of ProductProducer, then also i'd like to add this new(or current) productproducer in db_product

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for this purpose.

```
producer, is_created = ProductProducer.objects.get_or_create(name=name, defaults={'slug': slug})
```

If there was already an object with that name, it is fetched from the DB and stored int he variable `producer`, and `is_created` is False. If there was not yet an object with that name, one is created with the given slug, stored in the variable `producer`, and `is_created` is True.